# Not able to expand Ubuntu partition using Gparted Live USB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I need to extend my Ubuntu 20.04 (which is dual booted with windows10) Filesystem Partition `(sda9)` using the unallocated space `(26.37GB)`, which I obtained by shrinking `sda7` in Windows10 `diskmgmt`. But I am unable to do so, there is not space for the slider to slide. The drives are unmounted. I have also disabled swap and commented the swap related line /etc/fstab.

[Here is a link to the gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51RvT.jpg)

Here is the output to `sudo fdisk -lu` :

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 54.97 MiB, 57618432 bytes, 112536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 210.12 MiB, 220319744 bytes, 430312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 29.84 MiB, 31272960 bytes, 61080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10JPCX-24U
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A7466BD7-29D5-4D80-81DB-8B919AEA2A80

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2582528    4630527    2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda4     4630528    4892671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     4892672  444007578  439114907 209.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   444008448  445669375    1660928   811M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7   445671424 1610074111 1164402688 555.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  1665372160 1828229119  162856960  77.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9  1828229120 1866268671   38039552  18.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1866268672 1870174207    3905536   1.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda11 1870174208 1922603007   52428800    25G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda12 1922603008 1953523711   30920704  14.8G Windows recovery environment




Disk /dev/sdb: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x01ec8227

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30595071 30593024 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Here's the output to `neofetch`:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 80E5 Lenovo G50-80 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 12 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2226 (dpkg), 7 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1366x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-light [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-5500U (4) @ 3.000GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1250MiB / 7892MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

I previously encountered problems with booting up Live USB. I followed the steps [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) to make it bootable.
Is there a better way to resize partition if this doesn't work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The unallocated space is found before sda8 as far as I can see so to expand sda9 you would need to first move sda8 and then you should be able to resize the sda9 partition.

Note 1: These are operations that carry a small risk of data loss. Make sure you have a backup of important data.

Note 2: Moving partitions can be very slow, so make sure you have time and patience.

Comment: How do I move partitions?

Comment: Simply select sda8, in this case, right click on it, choose move and it should permit you to move it to the beginning of the unallocated space.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda8 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/sda9 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda9 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: My problem was I was unable to move the partitions even after using live usb. Anyway, I expanded `sda9` by shrinking `sda8` in windows which gave unallocated space above `sda9` and then I could resize `sda9` towards left. I still couldn't use the unallocated space below `sda7`.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Dhanush It may be because sda8 has an unclean NTFS file system. Boot to Windows and run `chkdsk /f x:` (replace the x with the proper drive letter), and then use Windows Disk Management app to move that partition. Then you should be able to move/resize sda9 as desired. Report back.

Comment: @Dhanush Status please...